# When does hibernate release list of entities?

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose an [Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) was created which select a *non-empty* list of values. Then `criteria.list().get(0)` is called and return from some function. It is clear that this element exists in further call chain, but what about other list elements? When does they are released? When hibernate session ends or when?

Comment: Why are you not selecting only a max of one record? They should be relased from memory when the transaction ends and the entity becomes detached.

Comment: Are you using a long running session or any memory cache?

Comment: `Why are you not selecting only a max of one record` you are absolutly right , but question is not about "best practise" it is "how does it works". :)

Comment: It is **not** long running session, also **no** hibernate caches are used (they are disabled).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `Session` and not `StatelessSession`, the L1 cache will be cleared under several conditions:

- When the session is *closed*.
- When `session.clear()` is called on an active `session` instance.

You may also clear instances of a managed entity individually on an open `session` which manages the given entity by passing the entity instance to `session.evict(Object object)`.